# React loop component communication

Tags: reactjs, communication

Let's say I have a loop that renders two components in each iteration. What's the most efficient way to tell Component1 (and pass data to it, to re-render Component1) that Component2 was clicked. I.e:

```
render(){
    return (
        this.props.data.map((data) => {
            <Component1 data={data} />
            <div>
                <Component1> // this one should also know Component2 changed
            </div>
            <Component2 data={data} click={doSomethingWithComponent1} />
        })
    );
}
```

Pubsub is not a solution I can go with.

Answer (score 2):

Broad question. Two possible answers, a) pass a function and wrap with a parent and b) use Flux.

Using Flux, you would make Component2 trigger an action, letting a store know that data has changed and thus all components that listens to that store will update automatically.

Below is how you do it with passing a function and wrapping with a parent:

```
var Hello = React.createClass({
    render: function() {
        return <div>Hello {this.props.name}</div>;
    }
});

var Goodbye = React.createClass({
    render: function() {
        return <div>Goodbye {this.props.name} <p onClick={this.props.clickMe}>Click me!</p></div>;
    }
});

var Parent = React.createClass({
    getInitialState: function () {
        return {
            name: 'Unknown user'
        };
    },
    passMe: function () {
        this.setState({name: 'User with name!'});
    },
    render: function() {
        return (<div>
            <Hello name={this.state.name} />
            <Goodbye name={this.state.name} clickMe={this.passMe} />
        </div>);
    }
});
```

Here's a [Fiddle playground](http://jsfiddle.net/kb3gN/11534/) for you

Comment: That's not really the case I described, the tricky part is that the components are in the loop.

Comment: It'll still work, the trick is with the `Parent` component that'll handle the function passing.

Comment: If I change the state and the components in the loop receive the state all the components will be updated, I.e: I want component1 on iteration 4 to update when component2 on iteration 4 is clicked. If I update the state all the component1 will be updated

Comment: Yeah, and if you create a new Parent on each iteration that does all of this, it should work.